# How to extend a line when its slope is defined

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I want to extend my line by few centimetres on both sides without changing the slope.

Is there any way to do this

Comment: Use a straightedge.

Comment: can you give me the formula

I am having 2 points so that I can find the slope but I want to extend the line in either direction by same length

Answer (score 3):

Let the two points of the line $L$ be $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and you need to extend the line to $(x_3,y_3)$ and $(x_4,y_4)$  in their respective directions by distance $d$.

You can find the equation of  $L$ in form of $y = mx +c$.

Distance formula says $(x_3 - x_1)^2 + (y_3 - y_1)^2 = d^2$

You plug-in the values of $x_1, y_1$ and $d$ and replace $y_3$ by $mx_3 + c$. The only remaining unknown variable is $x_3$. The co-ordinates of the other end can be find out similarly.

Comment: Here how to find C value

Comment: It is embedded in the equation of line which you find by using points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). I hope you know how to find the equation of line given 2 points.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have the slope, then most certainly you have the angle at which the line is sloped. Simple trigonometry will do the trick.

Edit:
If your points are $A(x,y)$ and $ B(x,y)$ and the slope is k. Then Point $A'$ will lie at $A'(x+p*cos{\theta}, y+ p*sin{\theta})$, where $p$ is the length you want to add to your line and ${\theta}$ is the inverse tangent function of k.

Comment: can you give me the formula I am having 2 points so that I can find the slope but I want to extend the line in either direction by same length

Comment: What is the _the inverse tangent function of k_?